# Datepicker with run at server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I need a date picker that pops up when you click on the relevant field, however since it is running at server, I think, jQuery does not work.
I need This date picker on Text box that will send value to sql server database.
What should I do?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles/jquery-ui-1.8.14.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=txtDateNew.ClientID%>').datepicker();
        });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateNew" runat="server" 
     CssClass="hasDatepicker form-control m-bot20 round-input"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear and the code you posted doesn't say much. Are the relevant jQuery libraries added to the site or have been referenced properly? whether the site is on a server or local does not really matter.

Comment: Me too, i don't understadn clearly the question. Is the jquery ui datepicker doesn't work on production server ?

Comment: how can i user jquery date picker in asp.net page that run at server ?